# VBA to find Second sunday for March every year

Tags: vba, excel

I have an if condition in my VBA code to check if it is spring Day light savings day, which is the second Sunday of March. The below code works for all except when 3/1/2015 (for example) is Sunday, then this shows 3rd Sunday. I can add another condition to check if it is Sunday then don't add 7 to the formula, but is there a better way of doing this?

If my_date = (DATEVALUE("3/1/" & this_year) + 7+ CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("3/1/" & this_year), 1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1))

Comment: This formula works:                                                                        my_date =  DATEVALUE("3/1/"&this_year)+6-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("3/1/"&this_year),3)+7

Comment: I recommend not to use DATEVALUE() that may breaks if you are in a country where DD/MM/YYYY format is used instead of MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Ended up using:                                                                                    DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1) + 6 - WorksheetFunction.Weekday(DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1), 3) + 7 :-  For VBA                                                                                              DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1) + 6 - Weekday(DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1), 3) + 7 :- For  Excel

Comment: Since you've found something that worked and other "Answers" were posted that apparently did not meet your requirements, please put your code in an "Answer" which can be upvoted and which you can (in a while) mark as "the" Answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will help site admin and others who may have the same question and are searching for an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

For VBA :
DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1) + 6 - WorksheetFunction.Weekday(DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1), 3) + 7

For Excel:
DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1) + 6 - Weekday(DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1), 3) + 7

Answer (score 1):

If you start from the last day of the *previous* month, you can correctly calculate the second Sunday of the target month, even if it begins on a Sunday.

The following code sample calculates the start and end date/time of Daylight Saving Time for US areas that observe DST.

If you are developing a function to do this, be sure to test years like 2020 where March begins on a Sunday.

```vb
Dim dteLast As Date
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date

' DST starts on the second Sunday in March at 2 AM
dteLast = DateSerial(Year(dteDate), 3, 1) - 1
dteStart = dteLast - Weekday(dteLast) + 15 + TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)

' DST ends on the first Sunday in November at 2 AM
dteLast = DateSerial(Year(dteDate), 11, 1) - 1
dteEnd = dteLast - Weekday(dteLast) + 8 + TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter the year you want to look at in Cell A1, then select a cell where you want to see the date of the 2nd Sunday in March for the given year and run this code:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim dt As Date
Dim y As Integer

i = 0
y = Range("A1").Value
dt = "3/1/" & y

While i < 2

If WeekdayName(Weekday(dt), False, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) = "Sunday" Then

i = i + 1
If i <> 2 Then
dt = DateAdd("d", 1, dt)
End If

Else

If i <> 2 Then
dt = DateAdd("d", 1, dt)
End If

End If

Wend

ActiveCell.Value = dt

End Sub
```

Comment: I was looking for way to edit my formula without having to check for sunday

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would just add this below code for anyone else who comes across this. I wanted to create a GENERAL purpose block of code that gets any day of week of any month. Ie. if I want the second Sunday or the last Sunday I could retrieve this from one function. Thus I have written the below. You can alter it to how you need it. Ie. Sunday/ Monday or first, second or third etc. This is done by cycling through the days of the month and if the day return which ever day of week you are looking for you save the day in a collection. Once your have cycled through the month you then cycle through the collection to retrieve the necessary date you need!

```
Function DayOfMonth(theDate As String) As String
    'cycle through the given month
    'check each day of month and if sunday add day of month to collection
    'then cycle through collection for required sunday of month
    'daylight savings only happens in march and november
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long
    Dim testDate As String 'this get passed through function
    Dim theYear As Long, theMonth As Long
    Dim dayCollection As New Collection

    theYear = Year(theDate)
    theMonth = Month(theDate)

    'build collection of sunday's day of month
    For i = 1 To 31
        testDate = i & "/" & theMonth & "/" & theYear
        If Weekday(testDate, vbSunday) = 1 Then
            dayCollection.Add i
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To dayCollection.Count
        '2nd sunday
        If i = 2 Then
            DayOfMonth = dayCollection(i) & "/" & theMonth & "/" & theYear
        End If
        'last sunday of month
        If i = dayCollection.Count Then
            DayOfMonth = dayCollection(i) & "/" & theMonth & "/" & theYear
        End If
    Next i

    'clear collection
    Set dayCollection = New Collection

End Function
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification to Slubee's answer which I find a little more elegant and easier to follow:

```
DateSerial(Year, 3, 1) - WorksheetFunction.Weekday(DateSerial(Year, 3, 1), 2) + 14
```

The 1st term = the date value of March 1st

The 2nd term = a number between 1(Monday) and 7 Sunday)

So (1st term minus 2nd term) gives you the last Sunday in February... and clearly adding 14 will get you the second Sunday of March.

With this structure, the formula can more easily be adapted to similar use cases such as the start/end of daylight saving time in Europe (last Sunday of March/October) or the end of USA DST (first Sunday of November).

Answer (score -1):

```
If my_date = (DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1) + (8 - Weekday(DateSerial(this_year, 3, 1)) Mod 7) + 7) Then
```

Comment: If you feel an "Answer" is not good, you can downvote it (click the "down" arrow to the left). On this site, marking something as "not an answer" should only be used for off-topic, comments, spam, people posting other questions "on top of" your question, etc. Yeah, it's confusing... :-)

Comment: I came across this in the "Low Quality Posts" queue. Usually code only posts with no context become candidates for deletion.